# How to Merge Databases on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I am exploring Google Cloud SQL and I need to have the ability to merge data bases for continuous integration reasons but I cannot figure out how (on a Cloud SQL instance).

The `instance` contains three databases: `development`, `staging`, and `production`.

I would usually run a simular command on a server instance running MySQL with the following:

```
mysqldump -n -t -u <myUSER> --password=<myPASSWORD> development | mysql -u <myUSER> --password=<myPASSWORD> staging
```

If I try to run this command via a server instance that has access to the (remote) dB instance, I get the following error:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045 (28000): "Access denied for user
>   'myUSER'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to
>   connect

I am thinking I need to pass an IP address in the command(??) - But I do not know how.

SO my question is how would I connect to a `Google Cloud SQL instance` via another server instance that has permissions to access the (remote) database server?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

-j

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to pass `-h <DB-IP>` in the command.

i.e.:

```
mysqldump -n -t -u <myUSER> -h <XXX.XXX.XX.XXX> -p<myPASSWORD> development | mysql -u <myUSER> -h <XXX.XXX.XX.XXX> -p<myPASSWORD> staging
```